# How to get message count from Mosquitto broker

Tags: database, mqtt, mosquitto

How to get message count from Mosquitto broker which is installed in windows or can we access and query on the broker database?

Comment: What do you mean by message count? The total number of messages published? per topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look under the section **broker status** in the [manual](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html), as there are a number of topics that you can check depending on what you are after, for example...

> **$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/+** The moving average of the number
>   of all types of MQTT messages received by the broker over different
>   time intervals. The final "+" of the hierarchy can be 1min, 5min or
>   15min. The value returned represents the number of messages received
>   in 1 minute, averaged over 1, 5 or 15 minutes.
>
> **$SYS/broker/load/messages/sent/+** The moving average of the number of
>   all types of MQTT messages sent by the broker over different time
>   intervals. The final "+" of the hierarchy can be 1min, 5min or 15min.
>   The value returned rep resents the number of messages send in 1 minute, averaged over 1, 5 or 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for replying..!! Could you please let me know how can i execute the commands in windows installed broker ?

Comment: Mosquitto windows build should come with some command line utilities (from memory!) mosquitto_sub.exe (for subscribing to topics) and mosquitto_pub.exe (to publish to topics.) Therefore; ```mosquitto_sub.exe -v -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1883 -t $SYS/broker/load/messages/received/+``` more examples in the manual http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html

Comment: You may need quotations around `-t "$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/+"`

Comment: You may also need to escape the variable in bash e.g. "\$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/+"

Comment: Or you could use single quotes `'$SYS/broker/load/messages/received/+'` to avoid variable substitution

Answer (score 0):

This should also work in windows, I just checked in mac:

```bash
mosquitto_sub -v -h mosquitto -p 1883 -t '$SYS/broker/messages/received' -C 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Probably you just need to replace `mosquitto_sub` with `mosquitto_sub.exe` or the equivalent you may have installed.

From the [manual](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html):

> -CDisconnect and exit the program immediately after the given count of messages have been received. This may be useful in shell scripts where on a single status value is required, for example.

> Combine with -R to print only the first set of fresh messages (i.e. that does not have the retained flag set), or with -T to filter which topics are processed.